# Why is the console saying, Cannot read property 'helpers' of undefined, in my meteor app?

Tags: javascript, meteor

**main.html**

```
<head>
  <title>socialnetwork</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> postsList}}
</body>

<template name="postsList">
  <ul>
    {{#each posts}}
    <li>{{content}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

**main.js (client and server are exact copy)**

```
Post = new Mongo.Collection('post');

if(Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.postsList.helpers({
    posts: function(){
      return Post.find();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: There isn't enough code here to know why `Template` or `postsList` is undefined.  Please share all the relevant code.

Comment: This error usually means that the template isn't being found by the compiler. try adding `import './main.html'` in your client main.js

Comment: Fred Stark. I tried adding your code in the client but now it says post is undefined. Jmargolisvt. I didn’t include code from my console. The code that I put in the console was Post.insert({content: ‘This is the first post’, created: new Date( )}). Also for some context, I am a 14 year old beginner in programming when it comes to JavaScript, html, and css. I am doing a free course on Udemy involving JavaScript to further my learning on these topics.

Comment: Tim, have you gone through the Meteor tutorials on their site already? I think the issues you are running into should be covered there, if not explicitly then still how to avoid them.

Comment: Christian Fritz. Thank you for the information, I will try out the Meteor tutorials.

Comment: Hello Fred Stark. As an update to my situation. I tried your code again and it worked. I just had to retype  some code of my own. I would like to Thank everyone for their time and input.